# How does control flow in this recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

can somebody please explain the flow of control in this code:

```py
def test ( n, a , b):
  if n ==1 :
     return
  test( n-1,b,a)
  print( n,b,b,a) 
  print( 1+n) 

test( 4,"x1","y1")
```

and ****output as****

```
2 y1 y1 x1
3
3 x1 x1 y1
4
4 y1 y1 x1
5
```

I am not able to understand which function is executed when and what output is generated.

Comment: visualize your code execution using https://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 1):

First, the code calls the **test** functions sequentially. Each time reducing the value for argument **n** and swapping the values for arguments **a** and **b**. As long as **n>1** it doesn't print anything. When **n==1** the corresponding **test** function returns **None**, this does not affect the output. After that, all the functions that were called earlier, one by one, in reverse order, go to the print statements and display their data on the screen.

> ```
> test(4,x1,y1)
>
>     #call test(3,y1,x1)
>
>     test(3,y1,x1)
>
>         #call test(2,x1,y1)
>
>         test(2,x1,y1)
>
>             #call test(1,y1,x1)
>
>             test(1,y1,x1)
>
>                 return None
>
>         test(2,x1,y1)
>
>             print(2,y1,y1,x1)
>             print(3)
>
>     test(3,y1,x1)
>
>         print(3,x1,x1,y1)
>         print(4)
>
> test(4,x1,y1)
>
>     print(4,y1,y1,x1)
>     print(5)
> ```